# Is XSD error expected when a string field is required

Tags: xsd, wsdl, xsd-validation

String field in XSD declared as minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1", should a XSD validation error be expected when empty tag passed in the request.

Answer (score 0):

No, a validation error should not be expected for an empty tag when `minOccurs="1"` and `maxOccurs="1"` because those occurrence constraints mean that the ***element must exist once***; they say nothing about the ***content*** of the element.